# 3 bison shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: parsing, yaml, token, bison, shift-reduce-conflict

I am getting 3 shift/reduce conflicts for this code. Here is my code:

```
%{
#define YYDEBUG 1
#include <stdio.h>
int yylex();
extern int yylineno;
extern int yyerror (const char *);
%}

%debug
%locations
%define parse.error detailed

%token TOKEN_NUMBER
%token TOKEN_THEN
%token TOKEN_END
%token TOKEN_STOP
%token TOKEN_DO
%token TOKEN_IDENT
%token TOKEN_READ
%token TOKEN_world
%token TOKEN_NEWLINE
%token TOKEN_IF
%token TOKEN_ELSEIF
%token TOKEN_WHILE
%token TOKEN_POWER TOKEN_MULTIPLY
%token TOKEN_PROGRAM
%token TOKEN_ELSE
%token TOKEN_MINUS
%token TOKEN_WRITE
%token TOKEN_ENDIF
%token TOKEN_ENDWHILE
%token TOKEN_FULL_STOP
%token TOKEN_EXCLAMATION_POINT
%token TOKEN_COMMA
%token TOKEN_LEFT_PARENTHESIS
%token TOKEN_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
%token TOKEN_COLON
%token TOKEN_ASSIGNMENT TOKEN_DOUBLE_ASSIGNMENT
%token TOKEN_DIV
%token TOKEN_GREATER_THAN
%token TOKEN_LESS_THAN
%token TOKEN_STRING
%token TOKEN_STRINGS
%token TOKEN_ADD
%token TOKEN_REAL
%token TOKEN_GT
%token TOKEN_SQUARE_ROOT
%token TOKEN_ARRAY
%token TOKEN_READ_STMT
%left TOKEN_ADD TOKEN_MINUS
%left TOKEN_MULTIPLY TOKEN_DIV
%right UMINUS TOKEN_POWER

%start program

%%

program:
    statements
    ;

statements:
    statements statement
    | statement
    ; 

statement: 
    simple_stmts
    ;

simple_stmts:
    simple_stmt TOKEN_NEWLINE
    | simple_stmt
    ;

simple_stmt:
    expression
    | write_stmt
    | assignment
    | if_stmt
    | elseif
    | else
    | do_loop
    ;

if_stmt:
    TOKEN_IF atom TOKEN_THEN TOKEN_NEWLINE statements TOKEN_ENDIF
    ;

elseif:
    TOKEN_ELSEIF atom TOKEN_THEN TOKEN_NEWLINE
    ;

else:
    TOKEN_ELSE TOKEN_NEWLINE
    ;

do_loop:
    TOKEN_DO atom assignment
    ;

write_stmt:
    TOKEN_WRITE atom
    | write_stmt TOKEN_COMMA atom
    | TOKEN_WRITE conditions
    ;

assignment:
    expression TOKEN_ASSIGNMENT expression
    ;

expression:
    expression TOKEN_ADD expression
    | expression TOKEN_MINUS expression
    | expression TOKEN_MULTIPLY expression
    | expression TOKEN_DIV expression
    | expression TOKEN_POWER expression
    | TOKEN_MINUS expression %prec UMINUS
    | TOKEN_SQUARE_ROOT atom
    | atom TOKEN_COMMA
    | atom
    | conditions
    ;

conditions:
    atom TOKEN_LESS_THAN atom
    | atom TOKEN_DOUBLE_ASSIGNMENT atom
    | TOKEN_ARRAY atom
    | conditions TOKEN_GT conditions
    ;

atom:
    TOKEN_IDENT
    | TOKEN_STRINGS
    | TOKEN_PROGRAM
    | TOKEN_STOP
    | TOKEN_REAL
    | TOKEN_END
    | TOKEN_NUMBER
    | TOKEN_READ_STMT
    | TOKEN_READ
    | TOKEN_LEFT_PARENTHESIS expression TOKEN_RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
    ;


%%

int yyerror( const char *s ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error at line %d: %s\n", yylineno, s);
    return 1;
}
```

The conflicts appeared when I did the expressions section. Particularly these lines

expression:
expression TOKEN_ADD expression
| expression TOKEN_MINUS expression
| expression TOKEN_MULTIPLY expression
| expression TOKEN_DIV expression
| expression TOKEN_POWER expression
| TOKEN_MINUS expression %prec UMINUS
| TOKEN_SQUARE_ROOT atom

I have tried reviewing the left and right part of the math operations in the top but it still shows the conflicts.